# what is difference between login with gplus and login with google in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am confused between login with GPlus and login with google account through firebase.

Confusion 1:

If I use login with gplus there is on file called google-service.json need to insert in app folder but the same time I want to use the FCM that also gives a google-service.json. So I can't able to copy to file with same name in app folder.
how to handle this?

Confusion 2:

If I am using firebase authentication and enable the google sign in. then which token I need to send to server to validate. The token which I get from

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String t = acct.getIdToken();
```

or 
the token which I get from:

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
user.getToken(true)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
            // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
            // ...
        } else {
            // Handle error -> task.getException();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between those 2 classes. As you see in [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) class documentation there are some method that help you get informations and as you see in [GoogleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) there are other methods.

1. You cannot mix those 2 files. What you need to do is to migrate from [Migrate from GCM to FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).
2. Everything is very well explained here,
   [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) and here,
   for [Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

Hope it helps.